# how can i output multiple single PDFs using TCPDF?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have a table of content on my page. For each row, it has a check box. How do I achieve the function of when i click on submit button, each of those rows which are checked will be downloaded as a separate PDF file.

For example, each checked row is a PDF file here. Suppose if I checked for 5 rows, 5 PDFs will be downloaded.

Can i know how can i achieve this?  Or is it not possible to do that for TCPDF library?

If it is possible, I would appreciate if you guys could give me hints or some reading documentation to achieve this function. I have no idea how should i search for the solution for this function.  Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please put a code for single file here ? how can we help without seeing anything,

Comment: @YagnikDetroja I don't have code for this function because i have no idea how should i start it. Do you have any advice for this? Or any documentation that is related. I can't seem to find one

Comment: You would need to create the PDFs, then create a Zip file, add the PDFs to them and offer the ZIP file for download. You cannot download multiple separate files in a single HTTP request. Alternatively, you could try making multiple AJAX requests to the server - one for each file - and therefore be able to download each one separately. It's a bit more work to make ajax-based downloads work, but there are examples online of the JS code you'd need. (P.S. tcpdf's role in this is simply to generate 5 PDFs, the complication comes after that, really.)

Comment: @ADyson So does it mean it is recommended to create a zip file for bulk download? Rather than using Ajax cuz is more complicated?

Comment: Well, both approaches have their own overheads and complications - with zip you have to get the zip creation right (and tidy up the files on the server afterwards), with AJAX you have to add extra code to make the downloading work. Both have good and bad points. I wouldn't recommend either one necessarily. Build whatever you feel most comfortable doing and/or you think will give the best experience to your users.